# How to add tabs in fragment activity ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have bottom navigation bar in my app where I have 3 tabs Home,My library and Account respectively. I want to add 2 tabs in my My books fragment action bar and dont want to see them in other two fragments.When i am adding tabLayout in My library fragment.
It is showing something like this:[image]

Here I want to add Tab1 and Tab2 in action bar of my library fragment so that it can visible in this fragment only and not in other two fragments.

This is my code:

**fragment_my_library.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MyLibrary"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/my_tab"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabMode="fixed"/>


 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/pager">


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MyLibrary.java**

```
public class MyBooks extends Fragment {

private TabLayout my_tab;
private ViewPager pager;
private TabAdapter adapter;

public MyBooks() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_library, container, false);

    my_tab = view.findViewById(R.id.my_tab);
    pager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    adapter = new TabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Tab 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "Tab 2");

    my_tab.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
  }

}
```

**TabAdapter.java**

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return mFragmentList.get(i);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
 }

}
```

Someone please let me know what should I do. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: what is your problem right now, is it showing in all fragments or you want to show it inside actionbar?

Comment: @Asif ,It is showing in only desired fragment but i want to show it inside ActionBar.

Comment: ok got your problem, btw why do you wanna do it, because of the toolbar elevation shadow?

Comment: Yes I want to match it with toolbar to look good.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:tabMode="fixed"
      app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Do I need to add AppBarLayout in my fragment xml file.

Comment: No, without it the toolbar shadow will appear above tablayout. Or you can omit it but you have remove the toolbar elevation yourself.

Comment: oh , my bad, i didnt notice, you have a common toolbar for all fragments. So in this way you'll have two toolbars in this fragment.

Comment: So, you cannot use tabs inside toolbar with this design structure.

Comment: Yes bro due to common toolbar I am facing problem

Comment: The quickest solution for now is to hide the toolbar elevation so the tablayout will match with toolbar.

Comment: How can I hide toolbar elevation.

Comment: by using:  getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); in your activity where you defined the toolbar.

Comment: final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        assert ab != null;
        ab.setElevation(0);

Comment: No use as I said:      if (getSupportActionBar() != null) getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);